# Handling RANK (additional column in SQL Server) while executing Full Text Search in Silverlight enabled WCF

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, wcf, silverlight, full-text-search

Here is the code and applies only to Full Text Search enabled table in SQL Server. I want help in knowing if my approach is right.

```
Dim dbConn as ObjectContext = DirectCast(MyEntConn, IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext

Dim CurPrimaryKey as string = dbConn.ExecuteStoreQuery(of String)(String.Concat("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where table_name like 'MyTable'")).ToList()(0)

Dim FTSQry = "SELECT fts.RANK, * from MyTable as tbl inner join CONTAINSTABLE(MyTable, (*), 'ISABOUT(venkatesh WEIGHT(0.9), venketash WEIGHT(0.6))' AS fts ON tbl." & CurPrimaryKey & " = fts.[KEY] ORDER BY fts.RANK DESC, " & CurPrimaryKey

Dim FTSQryOutput = dbConn.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of MyTable)(FTSQry)).ToList
```

This query taken during debug, executed in SSMS gives expected output along with `RANK` column. Great. But executed in VS will not give output as the Entity Framework generated code for `MyTable` does not have the `[RANK]` column.

So, I added a class as below in the web project (Silverlight web project).

```
Partial Public Class MyTable
    Public Property RANK as Integer
End Class
```

Now the FTSQuery execution in Visual Studio happens fine. But the `RANK` column output is always 0 while SSMS gives correct `RANK` values for same query. If I change Integer to Double for `RANK` column output is 0.0. If I change to any other type, the column has Nothing as value.

Please help.

Comment: Ok no one tried. Fine. For the time being I got a work around.

Comment: Instead of dbConn.ExecuteStoreQuery, Using native DB call get the RANK value. Dim spCon as DBConnection = dbConn.Database.Connection Dim CurPrvFactory as DBProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(spCon) Dim spAdp as DbDataAdapter  spAdp = CurPrvFactory.CreateAdapter Dim spCmd as DBCommand = CurPrvFactory.CreateCommand  spCmt.Connection = spCon  spCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text  spCmd.CommandText = 'Qry'   Dim OutputDS as new DataSet  spAdp.SelectCommand = spCmd  spAdp.Fill(OutputDs)  Dim OutputLs as list(of MyTable) = OutputDS.Tables(0).TableToList <- VS Extension.